# Flutter_bloc get updated data from firestore without UI event

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, bloc

I am using flutter to exchange firestore data from few devices.

If I use StreamBuilder everything works fine, but I do not like mixing business logic with UI. I would prefer using BLOC as pattern using flutter_bloc plugin.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

But flutter_bloc works in this way:

Steps:

1. Event ------------------------> New data BUT NO NEW UI EVENT
2. Async Request
3. Async Response
4. State (mapEventToState)-------> ¿How do I get the new state?

As far as I do not have "UI Event" because firestore data is being updated from another device, I can not update State.

I could use something like this on the bloc constructor:

```
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> query;
  QuedadaBloc(){
    query = Firestore.instance.collection('my_collection').snapshots();
    query.listen((datos){  
      dispatch(Fetch()); // send fictitious UI event
    });
  }
```

But I think this is not the right way.

¿Any suggestion?

Many thanks.

J. Pablo.

Comment: Your proposed solution seems fundamentally OK to me. What are you primary concerns with it?

Comment: You will get 2 answers each time a user touch the UI: One as BLOC answer flow and another one for FireStore Collection SnapShot.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended way while using Flutter, Bloc and Firestore is to have the repository layer provide a stream of data from Firestore which can be **subscribed** by the Bloc in Bloc Constructor (or any other function; see this [example](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_bloc_with_stream)).

Then, based on the changes in the stream, **dispatch** events when you receive new data from Firestore in the stream. The Bloc can handle the triggered dispatch event to change the State of the Application in a similar way when the changes in UI trigger the state change.

```dart
class SampleBloc extends Bloc<SampleEvent, SampleState> {
  final FirestoreRepo _firestoreRepo;

  StreamSubscription<?> _firestoreStreamSubscription;

  SampleBloc({@required FirestoreData firestoreData})
      : assert(firestoreRepo != null),
        _firestoreRepo = firestoreRepo;

// instead of '_mapXEventToState', the subscription can also be wired in 'SampleBloc' constructor function.  
Stream<TimerState> _mapXEventToState(XEvent xEvent) async* {
    // Runs a dispatch event on every data change in  Firestore 
    _firestoreStreamSubscription = _firestoreRepo.getDataStream().listen(
      (data) {
        dispatch(YEvent(data: data));
      },
    );
  }
```

References:
[Comment 1](https://gitter.im/bloc_package/Lobby?at=5cad3ef20aad635019594d30) and [Comment 2](https://gitter.im/bloc_package/Lobby?at=5cad3ef20aad635019594d30) by Felix Angelov ([felangel](https://github.com/felangel)), flutter_bloc library creator in Bloc Gitter Chat